# How to redirect page with query-string to external webpage using APACHE RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a login page to an external security service. This service, after validating the credentials, will then return user back to the originating page using the referrer url, as in the following example:

```
http://{IP NUMBER}/MyWiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main_Page
```

or any call to a page in the site containing  **Special:UserLogin** in the query_string needs to be redirected to:

```
https://login.security.server.com/test/UI/Login?service=DSSEC&goto=http://{IP NUMBER}/MyWiki/index.php/Special:UserLogin
```

I have been testing with RewriteCond and RewriteRule without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Special:UserLogin [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Special:UserLogin
RewriteCond ?#%{QUERY_STRING} ([^#]+)#([^#]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://login.security.server.com/test/UI/Login?service=DSSEC&goto=http://%{SERVER_ADDR}%{REQUEST_URI}%1%2 [L,B,NE]
```

Ok, this is going to seem a little confusing, but here's what's going on.

1. Check if `Special:UserLogin` is in the request URI or the query string.
2. Create backreference matches for the `?` mark, the URI and the query string (this is very important)
3. Redirect the request to `https://login.security.server.com/test/UI/Login`, but using the back references from the previous condition to build the `goto=` param, and using the **`B`** flag, which URL encodes the backreferences. This way, the result is an entire URL, along with query string, that's been URL encoded. (The `NE` flag is there to make sure the `%` signs themselves don't get double encoded).

With these rules, a request for:

```
/MyWiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main_Page
```

Will get redirected to:

```
https://login.security.server.com/test/UI/Login?service=DSSEC&goto=http://123.45.67.89/MyWiki/index.php%3ftitle%3dSpecial%3aUserLogin%26returnto%3dMain_Page
```

As you can see, the query string `?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main_Page` gets encoded into `%3ftitle%3dSpecial%3aUserLogin%26returnto%3dMain_Page`, so that the **login.security.server.com** doesn't mistake it for its own query string. Instead, their login service will see the goto parameter as:

```
http://123.45.67.89/MyWiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main_Page
```

entirely intact.