# Using .htaccess, how to redirect a URL with Square Brackets [ ]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this URL:

```
http://example.com/main2.php?t202id=2483&mnin=pubd&t202kw=[zone]
```

to

```
example.com/newpage.php
```

but only if the visitor hit the URL with `[zone]` at the end of the URL and in case he visits a URL like this:

```
example.com/main2.php?t202id=2483&mnin=pubd&t202kw=XXXXXXXX
```

he must NOT be redirected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect page with query-string to external webpage using APACHE RewriteRule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202052/how-to-redirect-page-with-query-string-to-external-webpage-using-apache-rewriter)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use htaccess rather than php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ".*t202kw=\[zone\].*"
RewriteRule ^  http://example.com/newpage.php  [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Comment: This matches `t202kw=[zone]` _anywhere_ in the query string, not just "`[zone]` at the end of the URL". You should also match as much as you can in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (eg. `^main2\.php`) - if that is applicable. You could also make this compatible with Apache 2.2 by appending `?` to the end of the _substitution_ and removing the `QSD` flag.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier done in the PHP script than with htaccess. Something like this at/near the top of the main2.php script:

```
if ($_GET['t202kw'] == "[zone]") {
    header("Location: /newpage.php");
    http_response_code(301); // this is the HTTP code for "Moved Permanently" -- change to 302 if this redirect is only temporary
    exit();
}
```

Comment: "probably easier done in the PHP" - That depends if you know how to use Apache mod_rewrite! PHP is going to be far more verbose and less efficient and arguably more prone to error. Where should you use this PHP code in your CMS/application? `http_response_code()` is only PHP 5.4+ etc.